# How to create WCF services project with Default.htm

Tags: c#, html, wcf

Whenever we run the project, the Default.htm page should run during initialization.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create WCF Service Applications.
2. Add New Web Form file in our Creating Project.
   Ex: Default.htm (Web Form)